# Can I decrypt the iOS SDK refresh token to use for WebAPI Calls?

Tags: ios, spotify

After getting a valid `session`, an encrypted refresh token is included: `SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session.encryptedRefreshToken`. I tried using this refresh token to get an access token using [step seven](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/), but it failed. Is there a way to decrypt the refresh token to use for swaps?